# Azure Linux based web app Restart automatically

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I am Running Django Application on an Azure Linux Web App, I have noticed that after a certain point the application restarts.
when drilling down the issue, I found that the Container disk or memory is not sufficient.
My Image size is around 5-6 gb which is under 15 gb limit.
Is there any better way of Deploying Django application ?

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Grace-MacJones-MSFT [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19967#issuecomment-445986852), this may be due to Proactive Auto Healing feature.

> It is an expansion on the Auto Heal offering. Proactive Auto Heal is a feature designed to setup default auto heal settings for every web app so that if they violate [these rules](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/17/proactive-auto-heal/) then it will recycle the process.

This feature will monitor the high memory usage and slow response situations and restarts the app when one of these conditions is met.

We can disable this by following the below steps as mentioned in the above link:

> Go to the Azure portal--> your Linux Web App-->
> Settings --> Application Settings--> Under App Settings add “WEBSITE_PROACTIVE_AUTOHEAL_ENABLED” and set to “False.”